# Spring Boot + Hibernate + Flyway: don't run migrations on new database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I'm using Flyway to update the DB schema. Currently, the latest version of the schema is 3 (the latest migration file is named `V3__postgres.sql`).

If I run the application on a database which has an older schema version, Flyway executes the update scripts as expected. However, if I run the app on a new (empty) database, flyway tries to execute the update scripts, but it doesn't find any tables (because Hibernate didn't create them yet), and the app terminates on error.

I would like Flyway to **not** execute the update scripts on an empty database, since when Hibernate creates the tables, they will be at the latest version anyway.

If I understand it correctly, I should be able to use parameter `flyway.baseline-version` for this. My theory is that if Flyway doesn't find table `schema_version`, it should create it and insert a record saying that the DB is at version 3. But even if I set `flyway.baseline-version=3`, Flyway executes the scripts anyway. I also tried to set parameter `flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true` and their different combinations but I couldn't get it to work.

Do I understand the `baseline-version` parameter correctly or am I missing something?

**Note:** I'm aware that since Spring Boot 2 the parameter namespace has changed to `spring.flyway.*`, but I'm using Spring Boot 1 so that is not the problem.

Comment: The main issue here is that you have 2 competing mechanisms to manage your DB schema. That is what gives you troubles. Also letting Hibernate create (and thus manage) your schema is generally a bad idea in production (also your schema (keys, indexes etc.) will probably be different then the one with flyway).

Comment: jsut like @M.Deinum said, don't let Hibernate create the tables. We use Flyway scripts like V0_1__Tables.sql, V0_2__Sequences.sql, V03__Data.sql to initially setup the necessary DB objects and populate them and then use the version from 1 upward to evolve our database.

Comment: We have been using Hibernate to generate DB structures for years in multiple projects and multiple environments and we never had an issue with it. But while this approach is great for creating new stuff (tables, columns, indexes, etc.), it cannot be used for modifying or removing existing stuff. That's why we started using Flyway (for modification of existing structures). If we were to start managing the schema completely by Flyway (i.e. manually) , this would bring us a lot more work. The whole point of using Flyway should be to make our (developers) lives easier not harder...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved: I created a custom `FlywayMigrationStrategy` bean where I manually check if Flyway has been already introduced to the database (by checking if the migration table exists). If not, I run the `baseline` command. Then I call the `migrate` command as usual.

Here is the Spring Boot configuration:

```
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FlywayConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${flyway.table}")
    private String flywayTableName;

    @Value("${flyway.baselineVersionAsString}")
    private String baselineVersion;

    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayMigrationStrategy() {
        return flyway -> {
            if (!isFlywayInitialized()) {
                flyway.setBaselineVersionAsString(baselineVersion);
                flyway.baseline();
            }
            flyway.migrate();
        };
    }

    private boolean isFlywayInitialized() {

        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
            ResultSet result = metadata.getTables(null, null, flywayTableName, null);
            return result.next();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to check if Flyway is initialized", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As comments already mentioned, flyway and hibernate should not be used together to update the schema, but this does not mean that you can't use Hibernate at all to help you maintaining your schema.

**Baseline**:
This feature is definitely not designed to prevent migration execution on empty databases. This should be rather used when your database already exists (i.e. it has already tables and data, and you want to keep those data). For empty databases it is useless.

Example:
Suppose you have an existing database, generated with 2 scripts:

```
V1__create_tables.sql
V2__create_constraints.sql
```

Now you want to manage further schema updates with flyway:

```
V3__First_update.sql
V4__Second_update.sql
```

V2 is your baseline, meaning that migration of database will not execute migrations V1 and V2, because they already exist.

If you want to combine **Spring Boot + Hibernate + Flyway**:

- Disable automatic schema update by hibernate - as already mentioned, this might be dangerous (hbm2ddl.auto=false)
- Use Hibernate SchemaGenerator to generate a big SQL-file, let's call it `V1__initial_schema.sql`, like in this [old-but-still-valid article](http://www.javarticles.com/2015/06/generating-database-schema-using-hibernate.html).
- If you happen to have a database in V1 with [data you want to keep, you should baseline it](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing). Otherwise just start from an empty schema. (`flyway clean`) and migrate (`flyway migrate`). *WARNING: `flyway clean` will drop all your tables!*

Now you are ready to use both Hibernate and Flyway for each upcoming schema modification.
Let's suppose you have just updated your model:

- Use Hibernate SchemaGenerator to generate the same big SQL-file, let's call it `generator-output.sql`.
- Do a side-by-side comparison of `V1__initial_schema.sql` and `generator-output.sql`. This will help you identify the differences between the 2 files. Based on these differences, you can generate a new migration file, let's call it `V2__update.sql`.
- Do a `flyway migrate` on your database(s).

Comment: As you said: _V2 is your baseline, meaning that migration of database will not execute migrations V1 and V2, because they already exist._ This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to set the baseline version to my latest version so that Flyway doesn't execute the migration scripts. But even when I do it, Flyway still tries to execute the scripts. I guess my original question is whether I'm experiencing a bug in Flyway or if I don't understand correctly how baseline works (or how it works with Spring Boot). Based on your answer, it seems that the former is true.

Comment: @Jardo I don't know if it is a bug or an intended feature - I rather focused my answer on showing how you could use Hibernate schema creation feature and Flyway together. I am afraid that `hbm2dll.auto=true` and `flyway` will never work correctly together.

Comment: If I could get the baseline feature of Flyway working as advocated then it should work... if you think about it, this is the same problem as introducing Flyway to an existing database...whether the database has been created by Hibernate or some other way is irrelevant...

Comment: The problem is that when you start your spring-boot app, flyway is run before hibernate schema update feature, which is normal: Flyway is normally used to create/update the schema. I guess this is why you have this "bug". When you use baseline feature on an pre-existing schema (I mean it exists before you even launch spring-boot for the firs time), which is the intended purpose of baseline, it does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

By the way When I try a inserting new version, I have seen that case sensitive filenames are important.
Also everytime remember set this property: `spring.flyway.ignore-future-migrations=false`
I used `V100__script.sql` instead `v100__script.sql`